# calculating the remaining balance of an article in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I have created a table of orders that needs to be delivered to our customers based on if we have everything needed in stock. this is an example of how the table can currently look like:

```
OrderID     CustomerID          ArtID           Balance ToDeliver   Pickdate    Deliverydate
119829      Customer A          ARTICLE1        2       2           17/10/02    17/10/03
119829      Customer A          ARTICLE1        2       8           17/10/02    17/10/03
119833      Customer B          ARTICLE2        22      20          17/10/03    17/10/04
119347      Customer C          ARTICLE3        20      10          17/10/05    17/10/06
119475      Customer D          ARTICLE4        7       2           17/10/05    17/10/06
119476      Customer B          ARTICLE1        2       5           17/10/05    17/10/06
```

current insert statement:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE #DeliveryTable ( OrderID varchar(10),ArtID VARCHAR (16),ToDeliver numeric (16,6),Pickdate varchar (15), Deliverydate varchar(15), Balance numeric(16,6), CustomerID varchar(50))

insert into #DeliveryTable (OrderID, ArtID, ToDeliver, Pickdate, Deliverydate, Balance, CustomerID)
SELECT KORDERRAD.ko_nr AS 'OrderID', 
KORDERRAD.kor_Artnr AS 'ArtID', 
KORDERRAD.kor_rant AS 'ToDeliver', 
CONVERT(varchar(15), KORDERRAD.kor_ldat -1,11) AS 'Pickdate',
CONVERT(varchar(15), KORDERRAD.kor_ldat,11) AS 'Deliverydate',
ARTIKEL_LPLATS.lp_Saldo AS 'Balance', 
CustomerID.k_namn AS 'CustomerID',
FROM monitor.ARTIKEL ARTIKEL, monitor.ARTIKEL_LPLATS ARTIKEL_LPLATS, monitor.KORDER KORDER, monitor.KORDERRAD KORDERRAD, monitor.Kund Kund
WHERE KORDERRAD.kor_Artnr = ARTIKEL.art_Artnr 
AND ARTIKEL.Artnr = ARTIKEL_LPLATS.Artnr 
AND KORDER.ko_id = KORDERRAD.ko_id 
AND KORDER.k_id = CustomerID.k_id 
AND ((KORDERRAD.kor_rant>0) 
AND (KORDER.ko_status>0 And KORDER.ko_status Between 1 And 5) 
AND (KORDERRAD.kor_otyp In (0,1)) 
AND (KORDERRAD.kor_rtyp=1) 
AND (KORDERRAD.kor_ldat Between DATEADD(day, -14, getdate()) And DATEADD(day, 3, getdate()))
ORDER BY KORDERRAD.kor_ldat
```

current query:

```
SELECT 
     OrderID,
     CustomerID, 
     ArtID,
     CAST(Balance AS INT),
     CAST(ToDeliver AS INT),
     Pickdate,
     Deliverydate
FROM 
     #DeliveryTable
GROUP BY 
     Deliverydate,
     Pickdate,
     CustomerID,
     OrderID,
     ArtID,
     ToDeliver,
     Balance
ORDER BY 
     Deliverydate
```

what i need to do is that every time an article is listed the balance should decrease by the amount to be delivered for that row so the next row that has the same article will have the updated balance to check from.

so in the example above  the result would be something like.

```
OrderID     CustomerID          ArtID           Balance ToDeliver   Pickdate    Deliverydate
119829      Customer A          ARTICLE1        2       2           17/10/02    17/10/03
119829      Customer A          ARTICLE1        0       8           17/10/02    17/10/03
119833      Customer B          ARTICLE2        22      20          17/10/03    17/10/04
119347      Customer C          ARTICLE3        20      10          17/10/05    17/10/06
119475      Customer D          ARTICLE4        7       2           17/10/05    17/10/06
119476      Customer B          ARTICLE1        -8      5           17/10/05    17/10/06
```

is there a smart way to accomplish this using SQL? Our database is running on a SQL Anywhere server.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Please add SQL update/insert statements you are running.

Comment: added the insert statement